# Different results from MySQL when run directly/run via bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I run the code

```
user@host:~$ mysql -h mysql-server -uuser -ppassword scans -N -B -e 
'SELECT scan_id, count(*) FROM scan_info NATURAL JOIN found_results  
WHERE fp_id = "1669" AND timestamp >= "2016-08-31"  
ORDER BY scan_id  LIMIT 1'
```

And the result is

```
52169471    9
```

However when I run it via `bash -c` I got

```
user@host:~$ bash -c "mysql -h mysql-server -uuser -ppassword scans -N -B -e
'SELECT scan_id, count(*)  FROM scan_info  NATURAL JOIN found_results  
WHERE fp_id = "1669" AND timestamp >= "2016-08-31"  
ORDER BY scan_id  LIMIT 1'"
```

I got a different result:

```
51278887    23
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three levels of quoting if the above command. This will cause a problem with the inner double quotes. Here's the command that bash will actual execute:

```
mysql -h mysql-server -uuser -ppassword scans -N -B -e 'SELECT scan_id, count(*)  FROM scan_info  NATURAL JOIN found_results  WHERE fp_id = 1669 AND timestamp >= 2016-08-31  ORDER BY scan_id  LIMIT 1'
```

As you can see, the inner double quotes are gone. You can solve that, by escaping the inner double quotes:

```
bash -c "mysql -h mysql-server -uuser -ppassword scans -N -B -e
'SELECT scan_id, count(*)  FROM scan_info  NATURAL JOIN found_results  
WHERE fp_id = \"1669\" AND timestamp >= \"2016-08-31\"  
ORDER BY scan_id  LIMIT 1'"
```

Comment: With escaping the inner ", the difference got solved. Thanks!